# Inequality involving degree of irreducible representations

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

> Let $\rho:G\rightarrow GL(V)$ be an irreducible group representation with $W$ a subspace of $V$ being $\rho(H)$ invariant. Prove that if $m$ denotes the greatest degree of an irreducible representation of $H$ one has: $$\dim V \leq m [G:H]$$

Let us take $G=\dot{\cup}_{t \in T} tH$. Induced representations teach us to consider the following $\rho(G)$ invariant subspace:

$$W^o=\sum_{t\in T} \rho(t)(W)$$

Because $\rho$ is irreducible, one has $W^o=V$ and

$$\dim V=\dim \sum_{t\in T} \rho(t)(W)\leq \sum_{t\in T} \dim(W)=\dim(W) [G:H]$$

We need to show there is an irreducible representation $\theta:H\rightarrow GL(W)$ so that we can conclude $\dim W\leq m$ and finish this proof. We have no guarantee $\rho|_H : H \rightarrow GL(W)$ is irreducible so I am wondering if there is another way to do this.

Comment: by degree of representation, you mean dimension?

Comment: Yes! If $\rho: G\rightarrow GL(V)$ I mean the degree of $\rho $ is $\dim V$.

Comment: Areyou sure you don't want $\dim(V)\leq \dim(W)\cdot |G:H|$?

Comment: It was a two part question. We were asked to prove $\dim (V)\leq \dim(W) [G:H]$ and then conclude $\dim(V)\leq m [G:H]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can avoid using $W$ all together, unless I'm missibng something.
$\textbf{Edit:}$ Indeed I was missing something, the method bellow only holds if we take the base ring to be an algebraically closed field whose order does not divide the order of the group.

Denote by $χ$ the irreducible character corresponding to $ρ$ and by $\operatorname{Res}_H^G(ρ)$ the restriction of $ρ$ on $H$.
Let also $χ_1\dots,χ_r$ be all the irreducible characters of $H$.

Then there exist $a_1,\dots,a_r\in\mathbb{N_0}$, such that:

$$\operatorname{Res}_H^G(χ)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{r}a_iχ_i$$

With the above notation, there's a known result saying that: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{r}a_i^2\leq [G:H]$
Then, if we assume w.l.o.g that $χ_r$ is the character of highest degree in $H$, we have $m=χ_r(e_G)$ and by evaluating the above expression at the identity we get:

$$\dim V=\operatorname{Res}_H^G(χ)(e_G) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{r}a_iχ_i(e_G)\leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^{r}a_iχ_r(e_G)=m \sum\limits_{i=1}^{r}a_i$$

Since the $a_i$ are positive integers, we have $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{r}a_i\leq\sum\limits_{i=1}^{r}a_i^2$ and so using the previous results, we conclude that:
$$\dim V\leq m\sum\limits_{i=1}^{r}a_i\leq m\sum\limits_{i=1}^{r}a_i^2\leq m[G:H]$$

Comment: I guess in principle $V$ need not be a $\mathbb C$-representation, in which case character theory won't apply. But I agree with you that it's a slightly bizarre bound to try to prove

Comment: @Mathmo123 oh true, I've been seeing $\mathbb{C}$ so much that I just assumed it was the same here, I should note that at the answer, thank you!

Comment: How interesting that $\sum_i a_i^2 \ leq [G:H]$. I didn't know that. Could you add a reference or a short ideia of the proof?

Comment: I mean you still don't need $W$. $\rho|_H$ contains some irreducible representation $W'$ (which could be $V$ itself), and then my argument using Frobenius reciprocity still applies. The bound gets worse the more irreducible $\rho|_H$ is

Comment: I actually have it proven on a question I asked a couple of weeks ago, where I prove a slightly more general result. Here's the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4704279/sum-of-squares-of-coefficients-appearing-in-res-hg

Comment: I will read it carefully tomorrow. Thanks, @Fotis

Comment: No, we only need $ρ$ itself to be irreducible, not the restriction. Notice that if I had assumed that the restriction is irreducible, then the $a_i's$ I introduce would all be $0$ except from one, that would have had to be equal to $1$

Answer (score 1):

If $W$ is reducible, then it contains some irreducible subrepresentation $W'$. By Frobenius reciprocity, we have
$$1\le \dim\mathrm{Hom}_H(W', V|_H) = \dim\mathrm{Hom}_G(\mathrm{Ind}_H^G(W'), V).$$

Since $V$ is irreducible, we can deduce that $\dim(V) \le [G:H]\dim(W') \le m[G:H]$.

Comment: I am assuming $\rho$ is irreducible so $\rho(G)$ non trivial invariant subspaces must be the whole space, no?

Comment: Sorry. I'm not completely wrong. Yes you can deduce that $W^\circ = V$, but it doesn't follow that $\dim(W)[G:H] = \dim(V)$: it's not necessarily true that $W^\circ = \dim(W)[G:H] $, since the spaces $\rho(t)W$ need not be disjoint. E.g. take $W = V$.

Comment: $\rho(t)$ is injective, so it takes $\rho(t)(W)$ to another subspace with a basis with the same number of elements of a basis of $W$. So $\dim \rho(t)(W)=\dim W $... But you are right in saying that $\dim W^o \not= \dim(W) [G:H]$, we only have $\dim W^o \leq \dim(W) [G:H]$

Comment: Yes $\dim\rho(t)W = \dim W$. But it's completely possible that $\rho(t)W = \rho(t')W$ for $t \ne t'$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a slight adaptation of the original argument is enough to solve the problem.

$\rho|_H: H\rightarrow GL(W)$ is such that by Maschke's Theorem $\rho|_H=\oplus_i \rho_i$ where each $\rho_i$ is an irreducible representation of $\rho|_H$.

Let us take $W'$ the subspace associated with $\rho_i$. $W'$ is $\rho(H)$ invariant and therefore $W_o=\sum_{t\in T} \rho(t)(W')$ is $\rho(G)$ invariant, and because $\rho$ is irreducible, $W_o=V$. But this means:

$$\dim V=\dim W_o=\dim \sum_{t\in T}\rho(t)(W')\leq \dim W' [G:H]\leq m [G:H]$$

No need for Frobenius Reciprocity.